# cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath not called for multiple collection views in a single UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to have multiple collection views in a single view controller. I have tried to achieve that by using separate tags for each collection views, but it seems to me that the `celForItemAtIndexPath` is not being invoked. The following is my code for `UIViewController`.

```
import UIKit
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
  // MARK: - IBOutlets

  @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
  @IBOutlet weak var friendsCollectionView: UICollectionView!

  // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource
  private var interests = Interest.createInterests()
  private var friends = Friends.createFriends()

  override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .LightContent
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView.tag = 100;
    self.friendsCollectionView.tag = 200;
    collectionView.registerClass(NSClassFromString("InterestCell"),forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"cell");
    friendsCollectionView.registerClass(NSClassFromString("FriendCell"),forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"cellB");

    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    self.view.addSubview(friendsCollectionView)
    print("view did load")
  }

  private struct Storyboard {
    static let CellIdentifier = "InterestCell"
    static let FriendIdentifier = "FriendCell"
  }
} 

extension HomeViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource {
  func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    print("number of sections are 1")
    return 1
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    print("trying this")
    if collectionView.tag == 100 {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(Storyboard.CellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! InterestCollectionViewCell

      print("inside pluto")
      return cell
    }
    else {
      let cellB = friendsCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(Storyboard.FriendIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FriendListCollectionViewCell
      print("inside venus")
      return cellB
    }
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("hello")
    if collectionView == collectionView {
      print(interests.count)
      return interests.count
    }
    else {
      print("hmmm")
      return friends.count 
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone please suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you properly setup data source and collectionView delegates for both?

Answer (score 1):

To reach the cellForItemAtIndexPath method, you have to set the collectionView datasource like :

```
collectionView.dataSource = self;
friendsCollectionView.dataSource = self;
```

Also, it would be better instead of using tags to recognize each collection, using something similar to :

```
if (collectionView == self.collectionView) { } else if (collectionView
== self.friendsCollectionView) { // init friend cell ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the delegate and the dataSource of your collection.

```
collectionView.delegate = self
collectionView.dataSource = self
```

Remember to add `UICollectionViewDelegate` and `UICollectionViewDataSource` to your ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you correctly setup datasource and delegates? Since the class is not compliant to `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate`, I guess no. Do this in `viewDidLoad`:

   collectionView.delegate = self
   collectionView.dataSource = self
   friendsCollectionView.delegate = self
   friendsCollectionView.dataSource = self

or do it via xib.

2. Make the class compliant to `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate` by editing the class declaration:

   class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource
3. I suggest you to use references to objects instead of tags. Refer to the collectionviews by checking if the collectionView object of the delegates is equal to the one you've instantiated:

   if collectionView == self.friendsCollectionView { //do something }
   if collectionView == self.collectionView { //do something }